# How to Find Out What Upgrades My Lenovo Ideacentre K430 Supports?

Tags: graphics-card, upgrade, lenovo-desktop-computer

I have a Lenovo Ideacentre K430 and would like to upgrade its graphics card. In particular, I would like to upgrade to a [GIGABYTE GV-N760OC-4GD GeForce GTX 760](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125470). However, I do not know if my computer supports that.

How can I find out if I can upgrade to that particular GPU? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you checked the Lenovo site?

Comment: I have, but I am having trouble submitting a support request. It seems that they are limited to the Think line of devices.